# Use google-refine on csv without headers and with various number of columns per record

Tags: openrefine

I'm attempting to import in open-refine a csv extracted from a NoSQL database (Cassandra) without headers and with different number of columns per record.

For instance, fields are comma separated and could look like below:

```
1 - userid:100456, type:specific, status:read, feedback:valid
2 - userid:100456, status:notread, message:"some random stuff here but with quotation marks", language:french
```

There's a maximum number of columns and there aren't cleansing required on their names.

How do I make up a big excel file I could mine using pivot table?

Comment: what output format are you looking for? ie. How do you want to present/sort those data?

Answer (score 1):

If you can get JSON instead, Refine will ingest it directly.

If that's not a possibility, I'd probably do something along the lines of:

1. import as lines of text
2. split into two columns containing row ID and fields
3. split multi-valued cells on fields column using comma as a separatd
4. split fields column into two columns using colon as a separate
5. use key/value on these two columns to unfold into columns

Comment: Thanks a lot Tom,
I'll try to get JSON instead OR to develop your workflow in refine. If 2nd option is successful, I'll let you know.